# 70's or 80's youth sci-fi novel with vivid hyperspace, captured by birds in huge trees, drug addicted zombie-like people and castle endgame

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have, for a long time, been looking for a novel I read in my youth.
It was a pocket, and written for young readers 8-12?

I only remember fractions, in chronology, space travel (thoroughly and vividly described very colorful). I believe one traveller was lost in space.
The hero was captured, but manages to escape the back door of a moving vehicle. Only to be captured by birds and carried to nests in high trees.

Once out of that situation, in the city the people are drugged and in a zombie-like state. Somehow the solution is to sneak in to the large fort to save the day!

Comment: Reminiscent of1985's _[Child of Fortune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_of_Fortune)_ by Norman Spinrad, but too many things don't match

Comment: Thanks, but thats not it.